# Where should we need to change to show or hide the module from menu without using ui in Sugarcrm

Tags: php, crm, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I'm working on sugarcrm, I just want show/hide a particular module I created from top module menu without using the user interface(studio controls). At least want to know that whats happening behind the screen(what sort of code is triggered) when we enable or hide any menu from admin settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the "Display Modules and Subpanels"-page, your preferences are saved into your database in the table "config" with the values;

- category = 'MySettings'
- name = 'tab'
- value = a base64 encoded json-object containing which modules to display.

Decode your current data in the value column of this row and modify the json-object with the modules you want to add or remove, then encode it again and update the row in the table with your new value.